# How to insert a data from the same inputfields into a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, repeat, array

I,m trying to save data into a custom object from a repeated form in visualforce page. This is the visualforce code. Can I do do this using array? or list? or map?.. any idea?..

```
<apex:form>
<apex:pageMessages />
<div class="details">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
        <apex:repeat var="selectedproduct" value="{!selectedproducts}">  
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{!selectedproduct.Id}{!rowNum}">
                <h5 class="ticket-type">Ticket Type</h5>
                <h4 class="panel-title">{!selectedproduct.ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c}</h4>
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{!selectedproduct.Id}{!rowNum}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{!selectedproduct.Id}{!rowNum}">
                    <div class="icon-group">
                        <i class="gear-icon"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse{!selectedproduct.Id}{!rowNum}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{!selectedproduct.Id}{!rowNum}">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedproduct.Show_Attendee_Name__c == true}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firtname" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><i class="asterisk">*</i> Attendee Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pea.Attendee_Name__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedproduct.Show_Email_Address__c == true}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="emailaddress" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><i class="asterisk">*</i> Email Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pea.Email_Address__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedproduct.Show_Title__c == true}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirmemail" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><i class="asterisk">*</i> Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pea.Title__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>                                                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedproduct.Show_Company__c == true}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirmemail" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><i class="asterisk">*</i> Company</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pea.Company__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedproduct.Show_Dietary_Requirements__c == true}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirmemail" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><i class="asterisk">*</i> Dietary Req.</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pea.Dietary_Requirements__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!selectedproduct.Show_Comments__c == true}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirmemail" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><i class="asterisk">*</i> Comments</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!pea.Comments__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
        </apex:repeat>   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirmemail" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveAttendee}" value="PROCEED" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-proceed"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</apex:form>
```

But when I debug, it displays only the last data/form values.

```
DEBUG|ProntoEvents_Attendee__c:{Attendee_Name__c=zzxc, Email_Address__c=zxc@gmail.com, Title__c=zxc, Company__c=zxc, Dietary_Requirements__c=qwe, Comments__c=qwe}
```

How could I save the the values from multiple form?

[image]

This is my apex code.

```
public List<ProntoEVents_Product__c> getSelectedProducts() {

          List<ProntoEvents_Booking_Product__c> bookingproducts;
          List<ProntoEvents_Product__c> selectedproducts;
          List<ProntoEVents_Product__c> listproducts;

          listproducts = [SELECT Name, ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c, Show_Attendee_Name__c, Show_Comments__c, Show_Company__c,Show_Dietary_Requirements__c,Show_Email_Address__c,Show_Title__c  FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Id IN('a0T9000000Jple3','a0T9000000JplfL')];

          bookingproducts =  [SELECT Name, Quantity__c, ProntoEvents_Booking__c, ProntoEvents_Product__c  FROM ProntoEvents_Booking_Product__c Where Id IN('a0e9000000Bp7Ug','a0e9000000BpADo')];

         selectedproducts = new List<ProntoEVents_Product__c>();
          for (Integer i = 0; i < listproducts.size(); i++) { 

              if(listproducts[i].Id == bookingproducts[i].ProntoEvents_Product__c)
              {
                  for(Integer j=0; j<bookingproducts[i].Quantity__c; j++){

                      selectedproducts.add(listproducts[i]);
                  }
              }
          }
          return selectedproducts;

      }
```

This is the visualforce code for the SaveAttendee.

```
public PageReference SaveAttendee(){      


         system.Debug(pea);

        return null;  
     }
```

Initialization of `pea`

```
public ProntoEvents_Attendee__c pea{get;set;}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your controller code; otherwise we can't tell where your debug output has come from.

Comment: @SpongeBob updated sir.

Comment: That's helpful, but it still doesn't show where you're using System.debug() to get the output above

Comment: @SpongeBob already added sir..

Comment: Please include the code where `pea` is defined and populated

Comment: You're binding all your inputs to `pea` but `pea` isn't the variable you are iterating on.

Comment: @ChristianCarter what do you mean sir?..

Comment: Does your ProntoEvents_Attendee__c object has any relationship to ProntoEVents_Product__c?

Comment: @LanceShi yes it has..

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo You're looping through the collection selectedproducts but in every iteration of that loop you're just re-assigning the fields to `pea`. You also need to create a collection of ProntoEvents_Attendee__c's that you loop through and bind to.

Comment: @ChristianCarter Yes I used the selectedproducts for the display of the Product Name/ Ticket Name.  And also the render if the Field's would be available or not base on check box. I tried Map <Integer, ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> but it doesn't  suit my need, because it displays all the fields. Is there any other solution?..   How to bind the ProntoEvents_Attendee__c?.. Been this problem in 2 days.. Hope you can help me..

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this code for a bit, I identified the issue. It will not work the way you are doing it.

**Cause of issue**

- apex repeat is on a list of ProntoEVents_Product__c list while you are trying to gather details on a single instance of ProntoEvents_Attendee__c
- Single instance of an object will always save the last value of your repeat, that is why you are getting the last value only

**What you can do**

I am not sure of complete use case here but this statement -

```
<apex:repeat var="selectedproduct" value="{!selectedproducts}">
```

Needs to iterate over a List so that whatever changes you make will directly be reflected in your controller list variable.

Hope this helps. Let me know for further doubts in same..!!

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: What would I do to make it multiple data instantiate?.
is public ProntoEvents_Attendee__c[] pea{get;set;} applicable?.. 
or List<ProntoEvents_Attendee__c>[] pea{get;set;}?.. I tried them already.. But still I got error's..

Comment: Yes you will need to use List<ProntoEvents_Attendee__c>[] pea{get;set;} along with your page side Apex repeat iterating over this list somehow, if we are updating this list.

Comment: how about in vf page?.. I will not change something?.. {!pea.Attendee_Name__c} still works?..  I will try this.. Hope it works..

Comment: still no hope.. I got this error unexpected token: '[' at line 11 column 36..

Comment: Ok 2 things you will need to do. Use first apex repeat on ProntoEVents_Product__c list  and second apex repeat on ProntoEvents_Attendee__c list to get the inputs. If you can create a structure like that then you can possibly get all the inputs in controller

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose the relationship field in your ProntoEvents_Attendee__c object pointing to ProntoEVents_Product__c is called ProntoEVents_Product__c.

In your controller:

```
public List<ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> getAttendeeList() {
    List<ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> attendeeList = new List<ProntoEvents_Attendee__c>();
    List<ProntoEVents_Product__c> selectedProducts = getSelectedProducts();

    for(ProntoEVents_Product__c selectedProduct : selectedproducts) {
        ProntoEvents_Attendee__c attendee = new ProntoEvents_Attendee__c(ProntoEVents_Product__c = selectedProduct);
        attendeeList.add(attendee);
    }
}
```

In your page:

```
<apex:repeat var="pea" value="{!AttendeeList}">  
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{!pea.ProntoEVents_Product__r.Id}{!rowNum}">
                <h5 class="ticket-type">Ticket Type</h5>
...
```

Replace all the corresponding selectedproduct into pea.ProntoEVents_Product__r.

Haven't tested this and not quite sure whether this will cause field not queried issue. But hopefully this will work.