# How to pass an array into an Apex Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, list, array

How to pass the array value from the form to an apex controller?.. Meaning this form gonna display 2 or more times depend on the product quantity.. But the problem is that I need to pass the values to apex data in array type. How can I achieve this?..

This is the vf page.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pea.Attendee_Name__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!pea.Email_Address__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!pea.Title__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>                                                       
<apex:inputField value="{!pea.Company__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!pea.Dietary_Requirements__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!pea.Comments__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
```

This is the apex code.

```
public ProntoEvents_Attendee__c pea{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the quantity upfront in your controller, then you can instantiate multiple objects to serve as placeholders and chuck them in a map with the key being an Integer index (1 to MAX_QUANTITY). Then you can iterate through the indexes and pull the corresponding placeholder object instance from the map and display it on the page. A quick starting point example:

**Controller:**

```
public Map <Integer, ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> peas {get;set;}

// In your constructor or your page action method
public YOURCLASS()
{
    peas = new Map <Integer, ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> ();

    // Create multiple instances (placeholders) 
    for (Integer i = 1; i <= PRODUCT_QUANTITY; i++)
    {
        peas.put(i, new ProntoEvents_Attendee__c());
    }
}
```

**VisualForce Page:**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!peas}" var="index">
    <apex:outputText value="Attendee {!index}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!peas[index].Attendee_Name__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!peas[index].Email_Address__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!peas[index].Title__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>                                                       
    <apex:inputField value="{!peas[index].Company__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!peas[index].Dietary_Requirements__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!peas[index].Comments__c}" styleClass="form-control"/>
    <br />
</apex:repeat>
```

**Controller Save Method:**

```
public pageReference save()
{
    List <ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> attendeesToInsert = new List <ProntoEvents_Attendee__c> ();

    for (ProntoEvents_Attendee__c attendeee : peas.values())
    {
        // Check only for populated fields (blank should be ignored I guess)
        if (attendee.Attendee_Name__c != null)
        {
            attendeesToInsert.add(attendee);
        }
    }

    insert attendeesToInsert;
}
```

This is not the only and not necessarily the best approach, but it's one of the many possible solutions. Tweak it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks anyway to your reply.. I will try this.. For further explanation about my problem sir.. Here is the link.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84731/how-to-insert-a-data-from-the-same-inputfields-into-a-custom-object/84920?noredirect=1#comment112194_84920

Comment: In order to fit this in your solution, I reckon you'll need to extend it a little bit and create a map of a map in order to keep track of attendees related to a product: `Map <Id, Map <Integer, ProntoEvents_Attendee__c>>`. I'll leave that exercise to you.